# asyncimageview slow rendering - uitableview

Tags: iphone, image, uitableview, asynchronous, cell

I have a little problem, I try to use AsyncImageView class for display some image from an xml file into my tableview, I find this class in a website and it work very well, the problem is that if I scroll down slowly the image are load almost immediatly, if I scroll down quickly the image take some second to load...this is the code

```
#import "AsyncImageView.h"


@implementation AsyncImageView

- (void)dealloc {
    [connection cancel]; //in case the URL is still downloading
}


- (void)loadImageFromURL:(NSURL*)url {
     //in case we are downloading a 2nd image

    NSURLRequest* request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];

    connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self]; //notice how delegate set to self object
}


//the URL connection calls this repeatedly as data arrives
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)theConnection didReceiveData:(NSData *)incrementalData {

    if (data==nil) { data = [[NSMutableData alloc] initWithCapacity:2048]; } 

    [data appendData:incrementalData];
}

//the URL connection calls this once all the data has downloaded
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)theConnection {

    //so self data now has the complete image 
    connection=nil;

    if ([[self subviews] count]>0) {
        //then this must be another image, the old one is still in subviews
        [[[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0] removeFromSuperview]; //so remove it (releases it also)
    }

    //make an image view for the image
    UIImageView* imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
    imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [self addSubview:imageView];
    imageView.frame = self.bounds;
    [imageView setNeedsLayout];

    [self setNeedsLayout];

     //don't need this any more, its in the UIImageView now
    data=nil;
}

- (UIImage*) image {
    UIImageView* iv = [[self subviews] objectAtIndex:0];
    return [iv image];
}

@end
```

and this is the table code

```
    // Customize the appearance of table view cells.
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    } 
    else {
        AsyncImageView* oldImage = (AsyncImageView*)
        [cell.contentView viewWithTag:999];
        [oldImage removeFromSuperview];
    }    
    elemento = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *indirizzoImmagine = [elemento objectForKey:@"Descrizione"];

    CGRect frame;
    frame.size.width=88; 
    frame.size.height=88;
    frame.origin.x=0; 
    frame.origin.y=0;

    AsyncImageView* asyncImage = [[AsyncImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame]; 

    asyncImage.tag = 999;
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:indirizzoImmagine];       
    [asyncImage loadImageFromURL:url];

    cell.accessoryView = asyncImage;    

    return cell;
}
```

how can i optimize the tableview?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that your network just isn't keeping up with the speed required to load each of the images. First I'd make sure your images are small, close to your frame size. Also, with the way you're loading the images, and they way iOS recycles table cells, it's possible you're loading images for cells that have been recycled. If this is the case, just canceling the load on your `oldImage` reference would work.